# How to add this marks and display total marks as in browser? link: https://api.myjson.com/bins/1dlper

Tags: reactjs, redux

how to add marks(s1,s2,s3) and display in browser with total marks?
here is the my code 
how to add marks(s1,s2,s3) and display in browser with total marks?
here is the my code
{
                    "110": {
                    "name": "Sadhya",
                    "class": 3,
                    "rollNo": 110,
                    "marks": {
                      "s1": 55,
                      "s2": 67,
                      "s3": 77
                    }
                  },
                  ....

```
class HomePage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      student: []
    };
  }

    componentDidMount() {

    fetch("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1dlper").
      then(response => response.json()).
      then(findresponse => {
        this.setState({
          student: [findresponse]
        });
      })


    }

    render() {


        return (


            <div className="col-md-12">
        {
          this.state.student.map((dynamicData, Key) => {
            let keys = Object.keys(dynamicData);
            let d = dynamicData;
            return keys.map(student => {
              return (
                <div style={{borderBottom: '1px solid black'}}>
                  <p>ID: {student}</p>
                  <p>Name: {dynamicData[student].name}</p>
                  <p>Class: {dynamicData[student].class}</p>
                  <p>Total Marks: {dynamicData[student].marks}</p>  


              );
            });
          })

        }
      </div>

        );
    }
}
```

Comment: It's impossible to say, we don't know where it comes from or what problem you've had implementing this so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var targetUrl = 'your url'
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            fetch(targetUrl, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    "Accept": "application/json"
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                                     //if required on api side.(optional)
                       "requestData": {
                        "username": "xyz",
                        "password": "abc",

                    }

                })

            })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then((responseJson) => {
                    resolve(responseJson)
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    reject(error)
                })
        })
```

Now ,this will return you the response in json format you can from here iterate it using for loop, for each or map and set the state as required.
Though this may get you into other error as **CORS ISSUE** To solve that you can add 
proxy:"https://api.myjson.com/" to your package.json

**UPDATE:** This is the code to hit the get api and after getting response you can manipulate it accordingly.

```js
export function Test() {
  
    var targetUrl = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1dlper'
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fetch(targetUrl, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                "Accept": "application/json"
            },
           
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                resolve(responseJson)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                reject(error)
            })
    })


}
```

and for manipulating the response (Since your response is object and not array I have used Object.values to get the value of all the keys of object.)

```js
 console.log("coming")
        Test().then(res=>{
        console.log(res)
          this.setState({
            arr:res
          })
          console.log(Object.values(res))
          Object.values(res).map((data,index,array)=>{
            console.log(data.marks)
            var sum=0;
           Object.values( data.marks).map(d=>{
             sum=sum+d;
            })
            console.log(sum+"sum")
          })
          
        })
```

P.S. Attaching the output
[image]

Comment: I'm not getting ayushi?

Comment: @Diwakar updated the answer with the exact code you required , if it solves your prblm plz accept the answer.

Comment: @Diwakar https://exploringjs.com/es2016-es2017/ch_object-entries-object-values.html#_objectvalues this may solve your concern. And plz try to explore too. :)

Comment: can you please send me complete code once.     Test.js:19 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
    at Test.js:19

Comment: @Diwakar you can use it inside componentDidMount

Comment: and kindly accept the answer to make others get solution easily

Comment: @Diwakar you can share the github link (pushing to github will also maintain your version) or codepen link.

Comment: I sent through wetransfer download files  check once.

Answer (score 0):

you can use some from my reference below

use http request like fetch :
[fecth documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/id/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

or using axios : 
[axios git repo](https://github.com/axios/axios)